# How does Google Analytics programatically detect mobile traffic with analytics.js?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

In my web app I enable certain features on mobile devices. I have two criteria for a mobile device:

1. Touchscreen
2. Device width < 640px

**What is the programmatic criteria Google Analytics uses? Is it like above, or user agent, touchscreen, etc?**

Reason: I have a feeling that GA's mobile pageviews is much higher than the number of times my feature loads.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

afaik the browser sends meta Information about the device so you can do f.e. your mediaqueries in css for responsive webdesign and Google will use these standard-Information as well